# Why Object.key return sorted value of particular object?

Tags: javascript

```
    var anObj = { 100: 'a', 2: 'b', 7: 'c' };
console.log(Object.keys(anObj));
```

> this returns  =  Array [ "2", "7", "100" ]
>
> though it is [100,2,7]  as key values of **anObj** object

Comment: Object properties are not ordered per the spec.

Comment: because the spec orders keys, which could be indices. http://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html

Comment: See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5525795/2715716) which deals with different versions of JS and links the spec in some answers, too.

Comment: thanks for the reference @NinaScholz

Comment: I will Check , thank you @TomášHübelbauer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The javascript object is built on dictionary-like data structure which may be implemented by 'binary search tree' that will sort their keys. And in your case, runtime treats object like a "array"(because you use number as key), it just sorts the index.

Comment: You should like to where it says that in spec and also for what versions of ECMAScript this is true, because I believe this has been a subject to change over time.